# I have a webpage which I can access via localhost but how can I set it online? CentOS on VMware Workstartion 15

Tags: linux, windows-10, centos, vmware

I have a webpage which I can access via localhost - let's say `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/`, or `192.168.44.128` (my VMWare VPS local assigned network IP - 192.168.44.128)

Here my public IPv4 address is 185.11.12.13.

In this case, I need to make it available online on my public IP - 185.11.12.13 just like any other VPS I buy from other providers are set available online. We just login to root and type `yum install httpd` and it is done and you can type in the public IP on your browser and the APACHE TEST PAGE is available.

How do I achieve it from my VMware Workstation 15?

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
- Installed: VMware Workstation 15 Licensed
- Internet working in CentOS meaning the virtual network router is setup correctly.
- Port 80 is working on CentOS and Windows 10 because test page showing at 192.168.44.128:80

I tried editing the Windows 10 `host` file and set config to:

```
192.168.44.128 185.11.12.13
185.11.12.13 192.168.44.128
```

Even if working when I type my public IPv4 in browser 185.11.12.13 it's only because I edited the Windows host file to redirect 185.11.12.13 visitors to  192.168.44.128, but it only works on my PC.

When I use a different PC with a different network connected, it can't find 185.11.12.13 and shows down/offline.

I have added inbound and outbound rule Port 80 allowed in Windows 10.

Please tell me how to get my VPS online/live on my public IP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand your network.

1. Your vmware workstation machine is NAT mode or Bridge mode?
2. Keep it in bridge mode.
3. Do you have any firewall in your enviroment if yes then do nattig from firewall
4. If you don't have firewall then do  natting from modem to the virtual machine

Answer (score 0):

> Please tell me how to get my VPS online/live on my public IP.

To make Apache publicly available, try these steps:

1. In your VM manager, set your VM adapter to Bridged mode.
2. Make sure your Windows firewall (as well as your VM's) allows traffic on port 80.
3. Configure your router to forward traffic on port 80 to the network IP of  your VM (not the Host).

If you are using NAT between your VM and Host (i.e. your VM and Host have different network IPs e.g 192.168.0.x and 10.0.0.x, 192.168.2.x and 192.168.0.x, etc.) then:

1. Use your VM manager to forward traffic on port 80 from your Host to your VM.
2. Make sure your Windows firewall (as well as your VM's) allows traffic on port 80.
3. Configure your router to forward traffic on port 80 to the network IP of  your Host.

*Carrier-Grade NAT*

Note that these instructions assume that [Carrier-Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT) isn't in use by your ISP. You can typically check this on your router by looking at the IP address of your e.g. WAN or Internet Port (or similar). This should be the same as your public IP (assuming no CGN is being used).

If CGN is being used, you will need to look into a service such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com).